# Handling string builders in right way

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am appending some strings to my string builder object based on some conditions as follows:

```
StringBuilder Sb_Appearance = new StringBuilder();

if (Details.IsNeat == true) 
    Sb_Appearance.Append("Neat");

if (Details.IsDressed == true) 
    Sb_Appearance.Append(",Dressed");

if (Details.IsDisheveled == true) 
    Sb_Appearance.Append(",Disheveled");

if (Details.IsInappropriatelyDressed == true) 
    Sb_Appearance.Append(",Inappropriately Dressed");

if (Details.IsAppearanceOther == true) 
    Sb_Appearance.Append(",Other");
```

if first and fourth condition goes wrong, my final string can becomes::

```
,Dressed,Disheveled,Other
```

and here I can get a extra comma. I have to find that comma if it exists in Sb_Appearance at first index and have to remove that.How can I do that.

Comment: Are these many items? Because you can also add them to a `List<string>` and use `String.Join` on that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest using a `List<string>` and joining it afterwards:

```
var list = new List<string>();

if (Details.IsNeat)
    list.Add("Neat");

if (Details.IsDressed)
    list.Add("Dressed");

if (Details.IsDisheveled)
    list.Add("Disheveled");

if (Details.IsInappropriatelyDressed)
    list.Add("Inappropriately Dressed");

if (Details.IsAppearanceOther)
    list.Add("Other");

var result = string.Join(", ", list);
```

I know that's not what you asked (you wanted the `StringBuilder`).. but this is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
StringBuilder Sb_Appearance = new StringBuilder();
if (Details.IsNeat) Sb_Appearance.Append(",Neat");
if (Details.IsDressed) Sb_Appearance.Append(",Dressed");
if (Details.IsDisheveled) Sb_Appearance.Append(",Disheveled");
if (Details.IsInappropriatelyDressed) Sb_Appearance.Append(",Inappropriately Dressed");
if (Details.IsAppearanceOther) Sb_Appearance.Append(",Other");

var NewString = Sb_Appearance.ToString().TrimStart(',');
```

Comment: Comparing boolean with `true`? Also that's matter taste maybe, but usually you add `Neat,` and remove last symbol. Btw converting to string and trimming it will produce two strings

Comment: @Sergey, it was a representation of the OPs question.  I'll change to be more correct.

Comment: I suppose this is more meta, but do you think it's more important to represent the question asked and supply an answer, or to modify the code presented in the question to a more correct form?

Comment: I always follow [Boy Scout Rule](http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/The_Boy_Scout_Rule). You don't have to make code cleaner, but its good if you will make it more clean

Answer (score 1):

Any reason why you add the commas first then the value? I would swap the commas around if you can.

```
StringBuilder Sb_Appearance = new StringBuilder();

if (Details.IsNeat == true) 
    Sb_Appearance.Append("Neat,");

if (Details.IsDressed == true) 
    Sb_Appearance.Append("Dressed,");

if (Details.IsDisheveled == true) 
    Sb_Appearance.Append("Disheveled,");

if (Details.IsInappropriatelyDressed == true) 
    Sb_Appearance.Append("Inappropriately Dressed,");

if (Details.IsAppearanceOther == true) 
    Sb_Appearance.Append("Other");

if(Sb_Appearance[Sb_Appearance.Length - 1] == ',')
    Sb_Appearance.Remove(Sb_Appearance.Length - 1, 1);
```